# How many variables for a recommender system?

Tags: regression, survey, recommender-system, survey-sampling

I'm creating a survey for 60 people. I'd like to measure their music, tv-series and purchasing tastes.

The survey will show a number of songs. People will be asked to say if they like it (1) or not (0)

EDIT:

[image: TABLE1]

Observations are users. Columns are songs by Marilyn Manson. The "y" is another random song.

My concern is that a small number of X can't capture the variability of users'tastes:

1. UTENTE 1 (user 1) loves music, but hate Merilyn Manson and hates tv series. Its values will be 0-0-0-0-0-0.
2. UTENTE 2 loves **only** country and love "Lost". Values will be the same.

By looking at the table UTENTE 1 = UTENTE 2.

What if I added some variability to my survey?

[image: TABLE2]

Things will change a lot! Way more, if I added many more songs.

My question is: is there a rule to set a reasonable number of variables to capture the variability of the observations?

In short: assuming that there is some kind of correlation among songs, 5 of them to predict another one, seems poor. 1 million would be enough, but that makes no sense for a survey.

Comment: This is a very subjective question. Take songs for example: I don't see how you can find out whether people like songs of a particular type by asking whether they like one or two specific songs specified by names that may or not be recognizable by name or that may or may not include their favorite song of a genre. // Crafting effective questions for a questionnaire seems to be more art than science.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. I've edited the question. Someone told me about "conjoint analysis"